# La guerra más cruenta de la tecnología... ¿Tabuladores o espacios?

Tags: discusión

#### Prólogo.

Más de una vez he entrado a mirar preguntas que me han hecho saltar de mi asiento debido a una explosión de indignación. ¿Por qué? Porque su [indentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) haría [vomitar a una cabra](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/First_Blood).

Inflamado y cegado por la furia, entro a editar la pregunta y descubro que el usuario en realidad se ha tomado la molestia de indentar correctamente su código pero el formateador de la página ha ignorado dicha indentación, simplemente porque el usuario ha usado tabuladores ([he aquí un ejemplo reciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/64010/revisions)).

#### Inicio.

Pacientemente copio-pego el código del usuario en un embellecedor de código online cualquiera y lo reajusto para que sea idéntico al código original pero con la indentación cambiada a espacios, a veces es una tarea ardua pero ¡pardiez! ¡el código bien indentado se ve genial!.

#### Nudo.

Pero la cosa se complica, hay algunos usuarios que acostumbran a pegar quilométricos [muros de texto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wall_of_text) que ya quisiera la [gran muralla emular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Muralla_China), pero mi amor al código indentado es mayor a mis ganas de [decirle al usuario que resuma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) así que insisto en mi ardua tarea, cosa que a veces me lleva a dedicar más tiempo a editar del que este tipo de preguntas merecen.

#### Desenlace.

Llega un momento que se me llevan los demonios y de pronto me pregunto ¿qué estoy haciendo con mi vida? ¿me imaginaba a mi mismo haciendo esto de mayor? Pero sobre todo...

... **¿Por qué no acepta el motor de render los tabuladores como indentación válida?**

Esto haría que preguntas que necesitan una edición para adecuar el estilo del código ¡ya no necesitaran dicha edición!

Comment: De hecho lo suyo sería que convirtiera los tabs en cuatro espacios. Y pensaba que lo hacía: [Stop expanding tabs into four spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285838/209901)

Comment: Lo ideal en este caso es algo peliagudo, yo soy un firme defensor de los tabuladores y tener que trabajar con cuatro espacios en la red SE me enerva. Sea cual sea la solución, lo ideal es que código correctamente indentado (con tabuladores, espacios o ambos) sea renderizado correctamente, me es indiferente el método que se use para ello :)

Comment: Propongo un epílogo en el que haya un duelo a muerte entre los fantásticos defensores de los cuatro espacios y los irresponsables seguidores de los tabuladores. Ganaremos por amplio... espacio ;-D

Comment: ¿¡Irresponsables defensores de los tabuladores!? ò_ó ¡exijo resarcimiento! Prepare sus testigos monseñor, que yo así haré con los míos. ¡Le reto a un duelo! «lanza con rabia un tabulador al suelo»

Comment: Siempre tabuladores. Debe haber un lugar en el purgatorio para los defensores de los espacios. Y en el infierno para los que no usan ningun tipo de indentación

Comment: yo si he usado espacios es desde que estoy en [es.so] hahah

Comment: **Siempre** espacios. Algunos trabajamos con terminales de texto de **80** caracteres, y nos gusta poder mirar **la línea completa**, sin tener que desplazarnos a izquierda o derecha. Para *dividir* las líneas, suelo usar algún punto *de excisión*: paréntesis, signos `?:.`. Con tabuladores, mi precioso y **practico** formateo *se pierde* :-( ( Si no lo digo, reviento :-D )

Comment: Es una etapa que tenéis que pasar, cuando seáis mayores os encontraréis felices indentando con los espacios. :P Coñas a parte, entiendo que los espacios son la mejor opción porque el código se renderiza igual independientemente del visor que uses. Un espacio es un espacio... los tabuladores, vete a saber tú lo que pueden ser.

Comment: En mi opinión, la opción **Ejemplo de código** debería abrir un formulario flotante, donde uno incluya el código con opción a darle formato de acuerdo al lenguaje. Con ello se evitaría darle formato como estar revisando las ediciones. :)

Comment: TAB, tecla inventada en la era de las maquinas de escribir. Usese solo para navegar entre controles del formulario o entre ventanas o pestañas. El objetivo inicial de la tecla, era "tabular" o organizar como una tabla. Ya no es practico ni util en el estilo de código multi-linea de la actualidad. Funcionaba bien en los 70, ya no.

Comment: @EmanuelVe me has convencido. El silicio es un mineral usado para crear vidrio... por lo tanto, como esto de los ordenadores es una cosa moderna que usa también silicio, mejor volvemos a soplar botellas ;P

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster nunca dije de volver a la maquina de escribir jeje, pero vamos chango... el código tiene que ser Human Readable y agnóstico del renderer. Osea cambiate a los espacios. Dejame convencerte en esta!!

Comment: Acabo de editar lo de la nave. ok, dejo un truco para indentar de a dos espacios. La explicación no debe tener espacios. El código en principio debe tener dos tabuladores. Reemplazas cada tabulador por 2 espacios... Resultado, 4 espacios, y queda en formato de código.... Por otra parte, cuando pegan código ven que está bien, todo menos las líneas iniciales y finales. Depende de cómo este, si todo está dentro, quitar los 4 espacios en el inicio y el final y luego haces Control + K. Si en cambio hay partes fuera. Seleccionar el código y control + K. En cada código. No seleccionar la explicación.

Answer (score 7):

El problema que presentan los tabuladores es que su representación es relativa:

- Si el tabulador tiene ancho 2, entonces equivale a 2 espacios.
- Si el tabulador tiene ancho 4, entonces equivale a 4 espacios.

Vale... Eso no es un problema ¿o tal vez sí? Depende del contexto:

```c
void funcion(ParametroDeNombreMuyLargo1,
             ParametroDeNombreMuyLargo2,
             Parametro3);
```

Si el tabulador tiene ancho 4 el código anterior quedará tabulado con 2 tabuladores (valga la redundancia) y un espacio (¿¿??)... Bueno, vale, el caso es que es legible... ¿Qué sucede si ahora el editor pasa a configurar el tabulador con ancho 2?

```c
void funcion(ParametroDeNombreMuyLargo1,
     ParametroDeNombreMuyLargo2,
     Parametro3);
```

Vaya, ya no se ve tan bonito. ¿Cómo se vería si únicamente se usasen espacios?

```c
void funcion(ParametroDeNombreMuyLargo1,
             ParametroDeNombreMuyLargo2,
             Parametro3);
```

Otro ejemplo con el que me suelo encontrar es cuando a alguien le da por alinear una serie de instrucciones porque así queda todo más chulo (ancho de `tabulador=4`):

```c
int var1            = 12;
string otraVariable = "test";
float unDecimal     = funcionCualquiera();
```

Si ahora el código lo abre otra persona con un editor con `ancho=2` entonces parece que el código lo ha escrito un mono borracho y el resultado final es menos legible que si se hubiesen ahorrado la floritura:

```c
int var1      = 12;
string otraVariable = "test";
float unDecimal   = funcionCualquiera();
```

Mientras que sustituyendo tabuladores por espacios el resultado sería exactamente el mismo para todos los usuarios:

```c
int var1            = 12;
string otraVariable = "test";
float unDecimal     = funcionCualquiera();
```

He usado un par de ejemplos sencillos pero las posibles combinaciones son ilimitadas y algunas de ellas con resultados bastante desagradables. Cuando alguien decora mínimamente el código el tabulador actúa como un caballo de troya que se cuela sigilosamente en tu código para convertirlo en una maraña a nada que te despistes.

¿Solución? Evitar el uso de tabuladores.

Comment: Estoy contigo, tal vez esté influenciado por la filosofía Python en la que usar tabulaciones o espacios no es algo trivial o meramente visual, y nos encontramos con esperpentos como [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/62851/15089) :). Un espacio es un espacio en todos lados, una tabulación vete a saber que es... Antes usaba tabulaciones ahora que soy grande ;) nunca, sea el lenguaje que sea. No me gusta abrir/pegar el código en otro editor y que todo esté descuadrado porque para él una tabulación ahora son x espacios o se ha colado una tabulación con nocturnidad y alevosía... :(

Comment: Yo hago `void función(\nint param1,\nint param2)` y arreglado. Y lo de alinear el = nunca, mucho trabajo para nada.

Comment: @SJuan76 yo me he encontrado con funciones con más de 40 parámetros o simplemente con funciones con 4 o 5 parámetros en los que los nombres de cada variable podía tener facil 20 o 30 caracteres (nombres compuestos). Poner todo eso en una misma línea genera código ilegible... y eso solo en el caso de llamadas a funciones. Imagínate tener por ejemplo una matriz de 10x10 de double con valores fijos...

Comment: @eferion Creo que no te has fijado en los `\n` (si hay alguna forma de formatear los comentarios dímelo...)

Comment: @SJuan76 si que he leído los saltos de línea... a mi no me resulta cómodo leer una función si los argumentos están en líneas diferentes y éstos no están indentados. Es por relación de dependencia... esos argumentos pertenecen a la función, luego no deberían ir al mismo nivel que el nombre de la función al igual que el código que pertenece a un `if` no se debería encontrar con la misma indentación que el propio `if`

Comment: @eferion no he puesto muy bien el ejemplo, los parámetros están indentados. Y bueno, si hay una función con 40 parámetros, el problema no es ni la indentación, ni si se usan espacios o tabuladores.

Comment: @SJuan76 en ese caso el problema se llama código legado y créeme que no es facil lidiar con él

Answer (score 6):

Mi respuesta va a ser breve.

Creo que la cuestión no es si tabuladores o espacios y que el asunto requiere una solución *universal*: **que Stackoverflow facilite a la hora de escribir nuestras preguntas/respuestas una especie de identador de código**.

Es decir, que el cuadro que se abre a la hora de escribir una pregunta o respuesta implemente funciones mínimas de un IDE en el que podamos identar cualquier fragmento de código seleccionado.

Si tomamos el código posteado aquí, lo copiamos y pegamos en un identador de código local o en línea, ¿por qué no se puede hacer aquí?

Creo que no sería tan difícil de implementar. Sería un pequeño icono más, por ejemplo a la derecha de la ***I*** o del icono de los ***Fragmentos***, que nos de la posibilidad de identar el bloque de código.

Comment: De hecho ya lo tiene, solo hay que seleccionar el bloque que quieras identar y pulsas `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider Gracias. No lo sabía.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando algún entorno integrado de desarrollo (IDE)<sup>1</sup> como Visual Studio, por ejemplo, usa el IntelliSense de Visual Studio para que, al pulsar la combinación de teclas *ctrl + k **+** ctrl + d* el código tenga una tabulación adecuada.

Después de tabular tu código, copia y pega el código en tu pregunta/respuesta en Stack Overflow; si el resultado no está tabulado, selecciona el código y pulsa la combinación de teclas *ctrl **+** k* para tabular el código en la pregunta.

<sup>1</sup> o el IDE que estés usando.

Para JavaScript/HTML/CSS, puedes usar la opción "Ordenar" disponible en el control *`fragmento de código`* disponible y puedes también usar **[jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)** para ajustar tu código javascript y JSON, entre otras herramientas online.

*Control Ordenar:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -5):

Los tabuladores son claramente superiores.

Usar espacios es como programar a bajo nivel, fijan un formato de forma innecesaria.
Usar tabuladores es como programar a alto nivel, expresas intención y de los detalles ya se encarga la vista del IDE o editor que uses.

Lo ideal sería que todo el mundo usase tabuladores de forma consistente, por ejemplo 1 por nivel de identación de código. Así cada uno podría configurar en su editor cuantos espacios de representación quiere y el mismo fichero de código satisfaría a quien quiere 2 espacios porque trabaja en un miniterminal y al que quiere 8 porque tiene una pantalla de 4K.

Pero la realidad está lejos de ser ideal. Lo que nos lleva al siguiente cuadro de decisión :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuanto más alto el número mejor para ti individualmente.

Conclusión: usa espacios.

Comment: `Así cada uno podría configurar en su editor cuantos espacios de representación quiere y el mismo fichero de código satisfaría a quien quiere 2 espacios porque trabaja en un miniterminal y al que quiere 8 porque tiene una pantalla de 4K` ... grueso error...no funciona de esa forma... fijate los ejemplos que dio eferion y veras que el argumento no es valido..

Comment: Si el uso de los tabuladores se limita al inicio de la línea sí que funciona. El uso de tabuladores interlínea es más complicado, pero dado que no hemos llegado siquiera a lo fácil no vale la pena ni el plantearse lo difícil. Fíjate que yo hablo de usar un tabulador por nivel de identación del código. No me refiero a separar la declariación de variables del valor asignado.

Comment: ah.. entiendo. la verdad que no tiene usos prácticos TAB, excepto para navegar un formulario. El objetivo que tenia en las maquinas de escribir genera esta tonta guerra entre los vagos que no quieren presionar 4 veces la barra y los cortos de vista que no entienden el codigo que no esta identado.. todos fallados XD.

Comment: ¿Soy el único que no entiende el cuadro de decisión? ¿De dónde salen esos números?

Comment: @Mariano Salen de mi opinión, no un estudio serio. Los números concretos no son importantes. Representan que lo mejor que puedes hacer (10) es usar tabuladores cuando todos lo hacen; el motivo es en esa situación las herramientas estarán preparadas para ello y se usarán bien de forma general. Y lo peor es usarlos cuando todos usan espacios pues tu código no se verá bien más que en tu propio equipo. Si usas espacios tu codigo se ve siempre igual en todas partes, pero quien use tu código no podrá verlo con facilidad como a el le gustaría; aquí el resultado siempre es aceptable pero no el mejor.

Comment: Añadir que **EL CAOS** está en negrita porque es la situación actual en el mundo. Los espacios son como el capitalismo, un sistema lejano al mejor, pero que funciona bien en **EL CAOS**.